# Python remove newline from nested lists

Tags: python

How do you remove newline characters from nested lists?

```
[['Item 1', None, None],
 ['1',
  'Name',
  'Sample_data \nSamepleData'],
 ['2', 'Sample_data\n test', 'test']]
```

How would i iterate through the list and remove every instance of "\n"?

Comment: Please let us know what exactly you're stuck with in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in list:
    item.replace('\n', '')
```

You should look up the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) before asking this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

That snippet should work:

```
def replace_newlines(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return list(map(replace_newlines, obj))
    if obj:
        return obj.replace('\n', '')

given = [
    ['Item 1', None, None],
    ['1', 'Name', 'Sample_data \nSamepleData'], 
    ['2', 'Sample_data\n test', 'test']
]

result = replace_newlines(given)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for x in range (0,len(list2[i])):
        for z in list2[x]:
            z.replace("\n", "")
```